# Busca com GET não funcionando

Tags: javascript, python, django

To fazendo um sistema que busca itens no banco de dados interno do sistema, e em API's como o Youtube.
A busca deve retornar videos(youtube) e dados (Banco de dados interno).
A API do Youtube ta em JavaScript, e quando clico em buscar, so retorna os videos do youtube. Se eu comento o JavaScript ai volta a retonar os dados internos.

A ideia é que retorne os dois ao clicar em buscar.

Segue o codigo JS do Youtube::

```
$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 3,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
       });
       request.execute(function(response) {
          var results = response.result;
          $("#results").html("");
          $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
            $.get("?search_box=", function(data) {
                var string = "<div class='item'>"+
                    "<h2>" + item.snippet.title + "</h2>" +
                    "<iframe class='video w100' width='640' height='360' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + item.id.videoId + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
                "</div>";
                $("#results").append(string);
            });
          });
          resetVideoHeight();
       });
    });

    $(window).on("resize", resetVideoHeight);
});

function resetVideoHeight() {
    $(".video").css("height", $("#results").width() * 9/16);
}

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("---");
    gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
    });
}
```

Aqui é minha view.py que faz a busca de dados internos:

```
def home(request):
    noticias = Noticia.objects.all()
    tags = request.GET.get('search_box')
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    tags = tags.split(',')
    if tags:
        noticias = noticias.filter(tags__name__in=tags)

    context = {'noticias': noticias}
    return render(request, 'busca/index.html', context)
```

O resultado de ambos tem que aparecer na mesma pagina, e com somente um campo de busca:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form action=".">
            <p><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type something..." autocomplete="on" class="form-control" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control btn btn-primary w100"></p>
        </form>
        <div id="results">

        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            {% for noticia in noticias %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ noticia.titulo }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ response }}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Não estou vendo onde você está fazendo a chamada que retorna os dados internos - só vejo o código que chama a api do youtube.

Comment: está no def home(request): @nosklo

Comment: Como esta funcão será chamada? É isso que você não colocou - faltou chamar a função

Comment: Ela ta sendo chamanda quando a pessoa faz uma requisicao na pagina de busca

Comment: A requisição chama o código javascript, não o seu código em python - pois tem esse evento `$("form").on("submit", function(e)` em javascript que é chamado quando envia o formulário. É esse o seu problema - faltou chamar o seu código em python

Comment: Como eu faria para o JS ser chamado depois que o codigo python seja executado?

Comment: Você teria que escrever código javascript que chama também o seu código python, dentro da mesma função.